# How to prove the inclusion of an n-sphere in an (n+1)-disk is n-connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Recall a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ is $n$-connected if for every $k\leq n$ and every commutative square $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \mathbb S^{k-1} @>u>>  X\\ @VVV @VVfV\\ D^k @>>v> Y \end{CD}$$ there exist:

1. a filler $\ell:D^k\to X$ such that $\ell|_{\mathbb S^{k-1}}=u$,
2. a homotopy $v\Rightarrow f\circ \ell \;(\text{rel }\mathbb S^{k-1})$.

Intuitively it seems to me the inclusion $\mathbb S^n\to D^{n+1}$ is $n$-connected. Indeed it "feels" possible to press the singular $k$-disk onto the boundary $n$-sphere of the $(n+1)$-disk and thus homotope it into the boundary.

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \mathbb S^{k-1} @>>> \mathbb S^n\\ @VVV @VVV\\ D^k @>>> D^{n+1} \end{CD}$$

**Question.** How to prove the inclusion $\mathbb S^n\to D^{n+1}$ is $n$-connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to do this if the map from $S^{k-1}$ is constant. Then one has a pointed map $(S^k, *) \to (D^{n+1}, S^n)$ which you want to homotope into the boundary, relative to the point; because $D^{n+1}$ is contractible this is possible. The same homotopy (considered as a homotopy of $D^k$ rel the boundary) gives you the desired result.

To reduce to this, apply the homotopy extension lemma to $(D^k, S^{k-1} \times [0, \varepsilon])$ to a choice of homotopy rel $S^{k-1} \times \{0\}$ between the existing map $S^{k-1} \times [0, \varepsilon] \to D^{n+1}$ and a homotopy between the original map on the boundary and a constant map. The easiest way to do this is to start by homotoping the given map $S^{k-1} \times [0, \varepsilon] \to D^{n+1}$ to the map factoring as $S^{k-1} \times [0, \varepsilon] \to S^{k-1} \times \{0\} \to D^{n+1}$ ("undo" the first homotopy to make this constant), and then tracing out the given null-homotopy of $S^{k-1}$ inside the boundary. In the end, the map $S^{k-1} \times [0, \varepsilon] \to D^{n+1}$ is the same as the original map on $S^{k-1} \times \{0\}$, has image inside $S^n$, and restricts to a constant on $S^{k-1} \times \{\varepsilon\}$. Homotopy extension induces a homotopy of the entire map from $D^k$, relative to the boundary, of course.

Now using the fact that $D^k \setminus \left(S^{k-1} \times [0, \varepsilon)\right) \cong D^k$, you just need to run the first part of the argument to the disc of radius $1 - \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems relevant. It is from [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html), p. 304.  The elegant formulation of the theorem and  inductive proof is due to J.F. Adams in unpublished notes.

**7.6.1** The following statements are equivalent for each $n \geqslant 1$:

$\alpha(n)$ Any map $S^r \to S^n$ with $r< n$ is inessential.

$\beta(n)$  Any map $S^r \to S^n$ extends over the disc $E^{r+1}$.

$\gamma(n)$ Let $B$ be pathconnected and let $Q$ be formed by attaching a finite number of $n$-cells to $B$. Then any map $$(E^r,S^{r-1}) \to (Q,B) $$
with $r < n$ is deformable into $B$.

The proof is by induction with $\gamma(1)$ being easy. It is then proved that $$\gamma(n) \Rightarrow \alpha(n) \Leftrightarrow  \beta(n) \Rightarrow \gamma(n+1) $$
of which the last is the difficult step.